# Which direction does half-wave plate rotate field?

Tags: optics, laser, polarization

It is well known that if you have linearly polarized light impinging on a half-wave plate with an angle $\theta$ = 0 between the fast axis and the field polarization direction, then the output light will have the same polarization as the input. Now if you rotate the half-wave plate, such that $\theta$ is now non-zero,the output polarization of the beam will be along 2$\theta$.

However, it is not clear which direction the field should rotate. For example, if I rotate a half-wave plate $\theta$ clockwise (from the perspective of the propagating beam), then the field can be rotated either clockwise or counterclockwise to end up at 2$\theta$ relative to its initial state. Or is there always a fixed relationship between the two rotation directions (that of the plate and that of the field)?

According to a quick test I performed using a half-wave plate and a polarizer, the field rotates in the same direction as the plate. However, I am not sure if this generalizes to all half-wave plates, nor am I aware of an argument supporting that speculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thought and discussion with a friend, the answer seems blatantly obvious:

By definition, if the polarization is at an angle $\theta$ to the fast axis of the half-wave plate at the input, then at the output it will be rotated by 2$\theta$, AKA it will appear as a mirror image *on the other side of the fast axis*. Thus, since the polarization is always flipped about the fast axis, its rotation should follow that of the waveplate, in agreement with my experiment.